# DataOutputStream() VS DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream())

Tags: java, io

The code at [Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/DataStreams.java) showed an example of using `DataOutputStream` class and `DataInputStream` class.

A snippet of the code looks like this:

```
//..
out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dataFile)));
//..
in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(dataFile)));
//..
```

I was wondering why is it required to create a new `BufferedOutputStream` when we create a new `DataOutputStream` ?

Isn't it redundant since this alternative works as well? : `new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dataFile));`

As [this page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/datastreams.html) claims, DataStreams already provides a buffered file output byte stream. So is "double-buffering" really required?

I've modified the 2 lines of code (output and input), taking away the `BufferedOutputStream` and `BufferedInputStream` and everything seems to work just fine, so I was wondering what is the purpose of the `BufferedOutputStream` and `BufferedInputStream` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wrapping the FileOutputStream in a BufferedOutputStream will generally speed up the overall output of your program. This will only be noticeable if you are writing large amounts of data. The same thing goes for wrapping an InputStream in a BufferedInputStream. The use of buffers will only affect efficiency, not correctness.

Comment: heys I do undestand the impact of buffers however this page (http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/datastreams.html ) claims that DataStreams already provides a buffered file output byte stream, so what's the purpose of the `BufferedOutputStream` inbetween it?

Comment: @Pacerier - That page is very poorly worded. A look at the source code for DataOutputStream shows that it does not do any internal buffering (except in passing to convert Strings to modified UTF8 format). Same goes for DataInputStream.

Comment: BufferedOutputStream made a miracle for me!

Comment: And don't underestimate how much of a difference buffering can make. Simply adding the BufferedOutputStream to my code turned a loop that writes three million floats one at a time from a 95-second operation to a 0.5-second operation -- a speedup of almost 200x!

Answer (score 4):

It's not redundant, it's just different. The `Buffered` variants add a buffering layer, speeding up IO operations by batching up reads and writes.

Instead of going to disk for every read/write, it goes to memory first. How much of a difference it makes depends on a variety of factors. The OS and/or disk I/O system also likely does some buffering.

Comment: What I don't understand is that DataStreams already provides a buffered file output byte stream. so why do we need to provide another BufferedOutputStream inbetween it?

Comment: The buffered output steam is what does the buffering.

Answer (score 2):

I used to think that the Java IO model was unnecessarily large, but now that I really "get it" I find it quite elegant. A BufferedOutputStream is an implementation of the Decorator pattern (google it... it's useful). What this means is that BufferedOutputStream simply adds functionality to the outputstream it wraps. Internally, the BufferedOutputStream calls what ever OutputStream it decorates.

Answer (score 1):

Buffered IO streams help you to read in bulk thereby reducing the IO cost significantly. IO perations are fairly costly. Imagine your application doing a full read/write cycle for every byte that is read/written as opposed to reading/writing a chunk of data in one go. Doing a Buffered read/write is definitely very efficient. You will notice a huge difference in efficiency if you gather some performance statistics in both the cases i.e w and w/o Buffered IO specially when reading/writing a huge amount of data.